# Pasar argumento "out" a una función y que sea declarado también como opcional, C#

Tags: c#, funciones, visual-studio-2017, función-personalizada

Estoy teniendo la necesita de pasar un pasar un parámetro a un función el cual debe pasar como `out` para obtener el valor luego de ejecutar la función, pero este además debe ser `opcional`, porque no siempre se requiere.

Al realizar esta declaración:

```
public int MyFuncion(int valor, out DataSet dataSet = null) { ... }
```

> Visual Studio muestra el siguiente error: **Un parámetro ref o out no puede tener un argumento predeterminado.**

Como una solución a esto, investigué y logré hacer el siguiente método que si funciona:

```
public int MyFuncion(int valor, Action<DataSet> dataSet = null)
{
    int retorno = 0;
    // .. 
    //....
    DataSet ds_Temp = new DataSet();
    ///....
    ///Cargar y llenar los datos en ds_Temp
    ///Valor = ......
    ///retorno = .......
    ///.....
    ///Asignar y Devolver el valor....
    dataSet?.Invoke(ds_Temp);

    return retorno;
}
```

Invocándola de cualquiera de estas dos formas:

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
int valor_retornado = MyFuncion(4); //Funciona
int valor_retornado = MyFuncion(4, x => data = x); //Funciona
```

> Pero podría ser un poco complejo de entender esto en el código para varios desarrolladores en el proyecto: `x => data = x`.

---

Por esta razón decidí probar usando el Delegado `Func<T>` o `Func<T, TResult>` pero no se que estoy haciendo mal, no me funciona de esta manera (Ejemplos):

```
public int MyFuncion(int valor, Func<DataSet> dataSet = null)
{
    int retorno = 0;
    //....
    DataSet ds_Temp = new DataSet();
    ///.....
    dataSet = () => ds_Temp;

    return retorno;
}

public int MyFuncion(int valor, Func<DataSet, DataSet> dataSet = null)
{
    int retorno = 0;
    //....
    DataSet ds_Temp = new DataSet();
    ///....
    dataSet = (DataSet) => ds_Temp;

    return retorno;
}
```

Invocándolas de esta manera respectivamente:

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
int valor_retornado = MyFuncion(4, () => data); // No retorna los datos 
int valor_retornado = MyFuncion(4, (DataSet) => data); // No retorna los datos
```

**Qué estoy haciendo mal?, hay una forma de que esto funcione usando el Delegado `Func<>`?**

Entorno: Estoy usando Visual Studio 2017, .NetFramework 4.0 y C#

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo de Myfuncion antes de que lo hicieras action?

Comment: @MiguelZarate Para qué debería agregarlo? No tiene relevancia, si antes de eso no funciona por decidí buscar una solución, ya que necesito retornar la data que contiene el `DataSet`, entonces sería como esto sin declarar el parámetro como **out** `public int MyFuncion(int valor, DataSet dataSet = null) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que te has complicado cuando la solucion es mucho mas simple, en este caso que planteas podrías aplicar la `sobrecarga` del método.

```
public int MyFuncion(int valor, out DataSet dataSet) { ... }

public int MyFuncion(int valor) { ... }
```

Entonces podrás invocar al método con parámetro de salida o no, según necesites

Igualmente el `DataSet` es un objeto que se envía por referencia, podrías pasarlo sin definir el `out`

```
public int MyFuncion(int valor, DataSet dataSet = null) 
{
   // aquí trabajas con el dataset del parámetro, 
   // si lo cambias la variable se vera afectada ya que se envía por referencia
}
```

Si lo invocas de esta forma

```
int result = MyFuncion(10);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
//código
int result = MyFuncion(10, ds);
//si aquí obtendrás los cambios del ds que pasaste por parámetro
```

recuerda que el `out` aplica especialmente a los tipos por valor, como ser int, decimal, etc, los objetos se pasan por referencia

Comment: Gracias Leandro, esta es otra solución que pensé, me gustó la explicación que hace sobre lo tipos por valor o por referencia. Pero sería tener el código dos veces casi repetido. _Qué ventaja me ofrece esto a diferencia de usarlo con `Action<>` que también funciona?_

Comment: como el codigo dos veces repetido, eso no es asi si haces que una funciona invoque a la otra, o quizas el codigo que notes se puede compartir lo llevas a una tercer funcion privada que reutilices

Comment: A comprendo, esto me faltaba en mi mente _que una invoque a la otra_, gracias por su tiempo y explicación.